# How to decrease load on rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .net, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4

My ongoing project runs with rails3.2 server and my model consists of tables which were implemented in .net application.

**To be clear,Iam using tables in .net application and displaying them with rails application.**

My problem is server is taking more time for executing active record queries.
How could i solve this problem?
Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Before you want to start decreasing the load, you need to identify what is/are causing that load on the application. Identifying the problem is more important before providing a solution. So, if you could update your question in a more detail, saying what is causing those issues, we can probably help you in understanding how to overcome them. _decrease load on rails server_ is a broad question, and there a many possibilities we could assume which might not be related to your application. How are you generating these reports ? Can you share your code ?

Comment: After n+1 and any base caching things, add some monitoring system like AppSignal, Scoutapp to gather metrics on where best to spend your time.

Comment: Yes,Main problem is with my active record queries and joins.Is there any possible way ? @KedarnagMukanahallipatna

Comment: Look for queries in development log and see the time utilized. Identify the problem, which query and then try to post it here with related models in case a simplified version could be suggested

Comment: To optimize your queries, to begin with identify N+1 queries, you can use this [gem](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet). Make sure you create `indexes`, by introducing `indexes` lookup will be lot faster. Also, make sure you benchmark the changes. It'll give you a deeper understanding.